# Is it safe to use performance.now() to calibrate time?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm wondering if I'm not foreseeing something that might be a problem with my approach.

```js
class RDate {
    constructor(serverIsoDate) {
        this.serverDate = new Date(serverIsoDate);

        this.localDate = new Date();
        this.localTick = performance.now();
    }

    getCompensatedDate() {
        return this.serverDate.getTime() + (performance.now()-this.localTick);
    }
}
```

I get serverDate periodically, but If the user leaves the webapp running for a long time I can guarantee correct time even if the user spoofs his clock.

Does performance.now overflows or get paused when the tab gets suspended?

I can detect how much the clock drifted or got spoofed by calculating the difference between localDate and localTick

```js
_spoofed() {
    return Math.abs(this.localDate.getTime() - this.localTick - (Date.now() - performance.now())) > 1000 * 60 * 60;
}
```

Comment: The user can modify the JavaScript locally, so even if this API does what you want, the user can always spoof it as well.

Comment: They can monkeypatch the `performance.now()` function, for example.

Comment: A safer approach would be to compare time elapsed server-side only, but that cannot be real precise because you cannot measure precisely the request time..

Comment: Have you detected any difference between successive calls to *Date.now* and *performance.now*? As far as I can tell, both use the same system clock. The user can change the system date and time settings between calls. Some browsers need a restart to reflect such changes, others don't.

Answer (score 1):

The MDN documentation on the [Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API) API says:

> Since a platform's system clock is subject to various skews (such as NTP adjustments), the interfaces support a monotonic clock i.e. a clock that is always increasing.

This seems to say that the clock used for `performance.now()` should be independent of the system clock.

I don't think its clock can be paused. The description of `performance.now()` says:

> The returned value represents the time elapsed since the time origin.

The time origin doesn't change when a tab is suspended, so it should include the suspension time.